# Get a good picture of a place using Google Places API?

Tags: java, android, json, google-places-api, google-photos

for my application android (I'm building for a project) I use Google Places API Place Autocomplete. After that I get details about the searched place with API, using https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos , obtaining in json a file like this:

```
    {
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "New York",
            "short_name" : "New York",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Manhattan",
            "short_name" : "Manhattan",
            "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Contea di New York",
            "short_name" : "Contea di New York",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "New York",
            "short_name" : "NY",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Stati Uniti",
            "short_name" : "US",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         }
      ],
      "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eNew York\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eStati Uniti\u003c/span\u003e",
      "formatted_address" : "New York, Stati Uniti",
      "formatted_phone_number" : "(212) 310-6600",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 40.7828647,
            "lng" : -73.9653551
         },
         "viewport" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 40.81804399999999,
               "lng" : -73.9339825
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 40.74734159999999,
               "lng" : -73.99703049999999
            }
         }
      },
      "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_recreational-71.png",
      "id" : "c9bcef33f0cc85eda31f1c7444e9b1a3b82c9a9f",
      "international_phone_number" : "+1 212-310-6600",
      "name" : "Central Park",
      "opening_hours" : {
         "open_now" : true,
         "periods" : [
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 1,
                  "time" : "0100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 0,
                  "time" : "0600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 2,
                  "time" : "0100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 1,
                  "time" : "0600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 3,
                  "time" : "0100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 2,
                  "time" : "0600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 4,
                  "time" : "0100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 3,
                  "time" : "0600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 5,
                  "time" : "0100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 4,
                  "time" : "0600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 6,
                  "time" : "0100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 5,
                  "time" : "0600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 0,
                  "time" : "0100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 6,
                  "time" : "0600"
               }
            }
         ],
         "weekday_text" : [
            "lunedì: 06:00–01:00",
            "martedì: 06:00–01:00",
            "mercoledì: 06:00–01:00",
            "giovedì: 06:00–01:00",
            "venerdì: 06:00–01:00",
            "sabato: 06:00–01:00",
            "domenica: 06:00–01:00"
         ]
      },
      "photos" : [
         {
            "height" : 1200,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111583076557131766621/photos\"\u003eRafael Coninck Teigão\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAc33mBON8XwskPfKrISJcvus6pM7XTbYsFXnXeZwW2zUco0wHRaEqjjqCKE3BmsiS4ZM_Q9j6tQa8xs8hqad1SLgLGDiyGAeHFRyEt78UMWWw9RNz1UiLZFRQa8CifGq6EhCzGLtJAtjT4PPEi7RYqcSDGhQKlSo6I7YoQhJIROTqbvusSjsrwQ",
            "width" : 1600
         },
         {
            "height" : 2988,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104909161094400326427/photos\"\u003eANTONIO CAPETILLO\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAA9fnzq3bxP0E-V_rZdk3olrOU6AQKifTR_dKGlwuufxDIoxpDrFoPeGqdyXIfsjDZrOJPBxFpet0mEkqDFVTLmXw5s__fmCUbdWtcukgEY4wkI1Jj7XMOGZQ62WimJh2kEhCrqMdfTRqBgFokwF7h9QkXGhSQy1liZEMQQXuwTK_nGXgxjmZh5Q",
            "width" : 5312
         },
         {
            "height" : 1366,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109672649035665226271/photos\"\u003eAlicia Delmar\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAihHKUp2eVP82I9Pj9xukMjdVu7E_3jLfvg7vLMic1z5KZkzJJPFW9-DTpTqU4XWfcIVv-YWocvvulWH4-GcycQkh7vBQqFNcEhnZ0DCDLYxpDJ_DmNiVu7-Hit9wvhmKEhC4-wXEgDRxxTyTLahp25ClGhRPP97CMFYgjGaQpZ_lJaGHTXwZeA",
            "width" : 2048
         },
         {
            "height" : 2160,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108857710720895365536/photos\"\u003eJean-Marc Lang\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAen56wSxGLbbq9_A7QZQBpB8TMzxyCLgs_gOW3SbTMSjL55jkhuJOT6ln2OJDSFZ0J5iBgPzJ5ThM75yFpiOPd5zx7Qm1uPP4MhBDB8EurqC6tDJ-YrrMswvxhXi1V-b-EhDJ1grjzQZgPxQ0Ct94bPy2GhTnbY7dVDnxGffhACdM-gkfBfdyYQ",
            "width" : 3840
         },
         {
            "height" : 1440,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116298014864569795669/photos\"\u003eRandy Magin\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAidIR8gFrRuqixjj_T9rcQaZdidAt7DW5iJuoJQzPi4NbKtMdVHEay1CD_kpV1HvqAmskFWfwgt0-CNzFuNJgCWBEo-Sv2zMJZggszyNjMQWjUfsSLDmZuVy2Iv2jukX6EhBBQxlBFc4wskoevmps4fHfGhRoIudzqk6FLmLSqpFHYRw4EUOCqw",
            "width" : 2560
         },
         {
            "height" : 1536,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108218123172890727518/photos\"\u003eFrank Bartschi\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAC0yQt52C1WjsBkt2UsHBtw95D4VlVQVzSNMXNuIaQlQvivtJd29PXgUFEBmTFRsa0JBylygSIlyhosIy2SplF5ztZebD99JcnhJJhMxhb5aud7Y84o1uXGJzV9Kg9gT5EhAEEdjX_RUBWE8X21rV-szuGhRFy8Rfgaox7rlgcZgDVoy4KzWpUQ",
            "width" : 2048
         },
         {
            "height" : 2988,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/113059354128521364825/photos\"\u003eDave Cheetham\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAA09WVY5Ng0Y6sMF7dX7esyX_I-jRf3kXHWV0uYs1Hf9IEWQO1yE7T3d-GyZ7zfsgURFi3_Rgj5HxlI2_28NX0V4aaItC4dLxQfoMSMxAQjnsIQYFympWc1kwNiyPS4N_UEhDdvuqroEXUUuGdv0jPTBt8GhRaaOICESEFUiisvu4dMyc-tOuxag",
            "width" : 5312
         },
         {
            "height" : 3480,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108768066312606594072/photos\"\u003eDenny Biasiolli\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAk0FxliYLoXeQZB56S24vxO3TVCWsQjsbfAHapwwjsMkB1gZLMRyLvvteCMsm4D7Kg340jhBvePJ-ZVLmW1PISlZGNX_XKUzZ9J3zcVIsf8HzuJkW7qqLbGilcWzB8HrlEhDyZbJq3bPlYD58swvshwrjGhQKD-oG7SQJ0y5aAOoF7Wg0SsvPyA",
            "width" : 4640
         },
         {
            "height" : 2992,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104294143246593033535/photos\"\u003eJuan Carlos Figueroa Bueno\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAApojXU0tnM1-icF5eDWOZ9zkiiirfTXU2t6uS04k5QJlBbnfo4SEIu8wYLvFpJXuOe9Nxm1JuShF0tk3GNf36_9T-K5Xnkr8ma9S0pkQ6exb7Dqx9ohs9xlg221nHu-UEEhA5Y_xyKUt3tEFjvlWXffn8GhSk0YFCmFshuHzh0sqKEnmrAHGKWw",
            "width" : 5312
         },
         {
            "height" : 1836,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102155866047920396039/photos\"\u003ePete Jewell\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAIGc8Il_XJ3-jGNDTzB25icXYFyVv2ZH94NUSo08Vs_8Xs7Pu7CNrOC7ApURf8vZu_bC54T3KxxJYykJatE8DTFsRkeW6OBQzSCc1KqTwR2v7wUI74ITBS5f8zHN5XJRNEhDcqZQB5onAH-OTm7OGjllAGhThwp-K8xpADCF96ScY36AuG_LBBg",
            "width" : 3264
         }
      ],
      "place_id" : "ChIJ4zGFAZpYwokRGUGph3Mf37k",
      "rating" : 4.8,
      "reference" : "CmRSAAAAHvgKoP-IYygSnMSm0BtXzCbwviQYPafy02hX4F50KaAgz7aehIUOC_LPZO_bfNt8vzBCjgqQrOgClmmqGBVCoOMfjhtA7YwEkxkno4hhBwfeZrkwZZtQjTIaEjAYsYlEEhDSCP8bwDMCJYWMLNW5RgK4GhR1EQLP5ac4sU5PzsNQzP_2IEPVZA",
      "reviews" : [
         {
            "author_name" : "Marco Ciampi",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/105301741990096472996/reviews",
            "language" : "it",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-PSZSH0zmZlw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAARE0/yMuO96i6nR4/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba5/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "nell'ultima settimana",
            "text" : "Come si può pensare di andare nella grande mela e non fermarsi a fare un tour in Central Park?.....\nSono stato a New York diverse volte in tutte le stagioni e vi assicuro che ho sempre fatto tappa in questa meraviglia nel cuore di Manhattan.\n843 acri. ll parco ospita diverse attrazioni: i visitatori potranno rimanere affascinati dagli splendidi laghi, dai bellissimi prati verdi e dai ponti mozzafiato.\nSi estende dalla 59th street alla 110th street di Manhattan. Il perimetro del parco misura circa 9,6 km (4km da nord a sud, 800m da ovest a est). Il parco è aperto dalle 6 all’una del mattino, 365 giorni l’anno. Sicuramente i giorni migliori per visitare il parco sono il sabato e la domenica, a patto che ci sia il sole, quando Central Park è popolato dai newyorkesi che fanno attività fisica o semplicemente passeggiano con la famiglia a seguito e la maggior parte delle strade che lo attraversano, sono precluse al traffico automobilistico.\nBellissimo!",
            "time" : 1504111096
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "Claudio Farinella",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/115354462463068198888/reviews",
            "language" : "it",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-c6s7BIj2hMs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAKaU/Qip29P5onrc/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba5/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "un mese fa",
            "text" : "Un polmone in mezzo Manhattan, da visitare assolutamente. Rilassante, con laghetti in cui è possibile affittare barchette e trascorrere una piacevole giornata rilassante in mezzo la natura. Si può fare walking, running, bike oppure semplice passeggiata. Molto ampio, armatevi di tanta voglia e scarpe comode. Molto frequentato. A metà trovate la fermata della metro alla 79 strada. ",
            "time" : 1499857126
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "Davide Tasca",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/103442822199842647635/reviews",
            "language" : "it",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-anPbwQdkDVs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAA8XQ/h2Yzykwq2Eg/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba4/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "una settimana fa",
            "text" : "Bello, enorme e ben tenuto. Molto suggestivo. Ci sono stato a fine inverno e mi ha colpito. Nelle altre stagioni deve essere ancora più incredibile.",
            "time" : 1503615026
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "Patrizia Costi",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/103243776276366462547/reviews",
            "language" : "it",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-D2Hfq5WEt3s/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/APJypA1ptRTqPjo8qWd0dK-7EpXB8-_YJw/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba3/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 4,
            "relative_time_description" : "2 settimane fa",
            "text" : "Oasi di pace in mezzo ai grattacieli. Bello ricercare gli scorci di molti film. Bello fare un pic nic sull'erba. Fastidioso solo o  odore degli escrementi di cavallo in alcuni viali. Per i bambini bello lo zoo. ",
            "time" : 1502559753
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "Silvia Mastropasqua",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/100306581637921841700/reviews",
            "language" : "it",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-GuSVOC3e7N8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGE/rTP0MSIGpNQ/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba2/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 4,
            "relative_time_description" : "3 settimane fa",
            "text" : "Premessa: la nostra visita è stata il 3 agosto. Quindi la mia recensione e i miei consigli sono basati sul periodo estivo.\n\nTappa obbligatoria nella visita di New York, se state più di 3 giorni.\nNoi l'abbiamo girata in bici ed è stato molto rilassante, ci è piaciuto molto. \nPro:\n- corsie riservate alle bici, con semafori, per regolarne il traffico, comodo.\n- una giornata immersa nella natura, dimentica di essere, a sua volta, immersa in una megalopoli = un effetto molto strano!\n- laghetti,ponti, gallerie, statue di balto e alice nel paese delle meraviglie, giardini curati in modo maniacale, fontane, un castello abbarbicato su una roccia che spunta in mezzo a un lago popolato da tartarughe...vi sembrerà di entrare in luogo incantato!\n- artisti di ogni genere faranno a gara per stupirvi e incuriosirvi e voi non potrete fare a meno di rimanere affascinati.\n- il prato è a unica disposizione delle persone: niente cacche di cane (che comunque altrove raccolgono), niente bici sfreccianti, perfetto per il picnic o anche solo per rilassarsi magari  all'ombra di un larice.\nContro: \n- affittare le bici all'ingresso di central park può rivelarsi molto caro...45 $ per 2 bici x 2 ore!Potrebbe lasciarvi esangui!\n- di bagni pubblici ce ne sono pochi e, anche se puliti regolarmente, hanno molto aflusso e non sono proprio lindi.\n- il chiosco dei panini fronte laghetto delle barche-modellini è carissimo! 30 $ 2 panini...abbiamo il dubbio che il proprietario sia lo stesso del noleggio bici!\n- anche se esistono corsie e semafori che gestiscono il traffico bici-risciò-carrozze-pedoni, esistono anche persone che se ne fregano beatamente delle regole e pur di attravesare in fretta rischiano di farsi investire!\n- il parco è grande, attenzione a non perdervi!\n- il parco ha tante fontanelle di acqua potabile a libera disposizione...ma l'acqua non è granché e noi l'abbiamo pure trovata un po' calda...che ad agosto non l'apprezzi proprio!\n- nel parco si ha accesso a Internet tramite free wifi...ma è gratis solo per 2 ore! Dopo pagate! Fate attenzione!\nConsigli:\n- se volete affittare la bici sappiate che: se avete il city pass o equipollente, molto probabilmente è compreso, ma difficilmente il punto di prelievo sarà all'interno del parco, il nostro ( compreso nel city pass explorer) era a 10 minuti a piedi dall'ingresso sud. Noi, ad andatura molto rilassata e soste varie di varia durata, ci abbiamo impiegato 6 ore circa per una visita completa. Quindi prendetevi tutta la giornata e...non abbiate fretta.Se vi fermate a guardare rimarrete incantati e farete tante belle conoscenze (gli scoiattoli sono i padroni incontrastati del parco).\n- Scegliete prima cosa volete vedere e come raggiungerlo, in questo modo potrete farvi un vostro tour personale. RICORDATEVI CHE IL RITARDO NELLA CONSEGNA DELLE BICI PREVEDE DELLE PENALI SALATE!\n- non fate il nostro errore! Rima di entrare nel parco dotatevi di acqua (almeno 1/2 litro a testa) e panini per il pranzo...ci sono molti chioschi dissemniati ai margini di Central Park che sono abbordabili! L' avessimo fatto noi!!! :(\n- alla consegna delle bici ( ma anche nella app del parco, che è gratuita) vi danno la mappa del parco: è oro! Conservatela come tale perchè la consulterete molto spesso, è facilissimo perdersi!N.b. : potete richiedere una mappa anche ai punti informazioni, sono poco distanti dagli ingressi.\n-Troverete persone che, per un motivo o per l'altro, intralceranno improvvisamente il vostro cammino! Occhi aperti sempre e attenzione a i pedoni \"suicidi\" che per attraversare rischiano di farsi mettere sotto...ma soprattutto...abbiate pazienza...abbiamo scoperto che la maggior parte sono turisti anche loro...e che alcuni si erano persi disperatamente!",
            "time" : 1502172422
         }
      ],
      "scope" : "GOOGLE",
      "types" : [ "park", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=13393458397880860953",
      "utc_offset" : -240,
      "vicinity" : "New York",
      "website" : "http://www.centralparknyc.org/"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

You can see in the JSON there is at some point photo_reference that I use to retrieve the picture of a place. But since photos are taken by users, some of them aren't good photos because don't show the place but something else near the place. 
For instance for Central Park I get these pictures:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipNpSABT4bcgrx10w17byekNUkUrsOrGXh-Pcqz2=s1600-w400

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipNb9zc-431dH3G4x_UblW5jpRUWcZe4Bs_fJZPo=s1600-w400

Where only the second one is good, but the first isn't

So, how I can solve this? 
Is there a way to get a good picture maybe made by Google itself? Thanks!